# VBA code to use cell value to select and show named range in a listbox in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hei 
I would like A1 cell value to point to a named range and show this in a listbox.  The value in A1 is text which corresponds to one of many named ranges in a price list. If I select for e.g. value 'list1' in cell A1 then the corresponding named range shows in the listbox. How can I do this with VBA in Excel ?

Comment: You don't need VBA, just use the `INDIRECT()` function.

Comment: Hei, thanks, I'm a bit new to this how would I use the Indirect() function to show the named range in my listbox ?

Comment: Validation rule: List; rule: `=INDIRECT($A$1)`, If the value of `A1` is `list1` then the validation list will be the array of `list1`'s cell values. If `A1` contains "A8:A15" then the validation rule will be `A8:A15`.

Comment: I'm using a mulicolumn userform listbox which is using VBA to select rows and populate workbook cells with numbers and text. Can I use Indirect() function here ? –

Comment: Sorry, I was not thinking in terms of a listbox but in terms of a validation list. When asking for advices on how to do something in VBA you are supposed to bring your code here, otherwise it's not education but programming, which we're not doing (for free). The vague description below could be the most you can get without even trying to create something upfront.

Comment: Hei, understand and I'm not looking for 'free' coding. Ive set up a new user form with listbox and set my named range from the value in cell B2. This value corresponds to named ranges in a price list. To load the correct range into the list Box, I'm using   :                                                 If rRange = "SK75SR3E" Then ListBox1.RowSource = "SK75SR3E". There are alot of named ranges in the list, is there a more effecitve VBA Method which could be used ?

Answer (score 0):

The VBA solution I would suppose:
Create an array with the numerosity of your named range
add each cell's value in your named range to the corresponding array position
join the array with commas and add the resulting string to your cell's validation rule.